# How to manage "angular element" routes inside vue component?

Tags: angular, vue.js, angular-elements

I'm trying to integrate an angular component inside vue making using of "Angular Elements"(Web Component). I have been successful in displaying the component in the vue but unable to get the routes working when the vue application is reloaded.

My Angular code looks like this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzdgmn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

[image]

So when I click on chat child link, the route changes from `/chat` to `/chat/child1`. But if I refresh the vue application with the redirected link, it doesn't display anything.

**Versions I use:**

Angular version: `6.1.5`,

Angular Element: `6.1.4`,

Vue version: `2.5`

**So my question is, how do we tell angular element to change its route, according to the changes to routes in vue application?**